# Megaparsec: Unexpected input consumption when using try

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, megaparsec

I'm currently writing my simple programming language parser in Haskell with megaparsec library.

I found [this](https://markkarpov.com/megaparsec/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html) megaparsec tutorial, and I wrote following parser code:

```
import Data.Void

import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer as L

type Parser = Parsec Void String

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme = L.lexeme space

rws :: [String] -- list of reserved words
rws = ["if", "then"]

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = (lexeme . try) (p >>= check)
  where
    p = (:) <$> letterChar <*> many alphaNumChar
    check x =
        if x `elem` rws
            then fail $ "keyword " ++ show x ++ " cannot be an identifier"
            else return x
```

A simple identifier parser with reserved name error handling. It successfully parses valid identifier such as `foo`, `bar123`.

But when an **invalid** input(a.k.a. *reserved name*) goes in to the parser, it outputs error:

```
>> parseTest identifier "if"
1:3:
keyword "if" cannot be an identifier
```

which, error message is alright, but error location(`1:3:`) is a bit different from what I expected. I expected error location to be `1:1:`.

In the following part of definition of `identifier`,

```
identifier = (lexeme . try) (p >>= check)
```

I expected `try` would behave like there was no input consumed if `(p >>= check)` fails and go back to source location `1:1:`.

Is my expectation wrong? How can I get this code work as I intended?

Comment: I guess that when `fail` is run, the position is `1:3`, since `p` consumed the prefix. Later on `try` rolls it back, but it's too late.

Comment: @chi Thanks. But why is `try` too late to roll it back? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Don’t confuse the error reporting with the state of the parser. The error occurred at position `1:3` (after the `if` was recognised). The parsing process did backtrack - if you compose `identifier` into a bigger parser using `<|>` you’d observe the other branch being tried at the initial position - but since it didn’t have any more alternatives to try the original error was reported. I’d fix it using a combination of `lookahead` and `notFollowedBy`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thank you very much. I misunderstood the notion of backtracking. However, I fixed my parser with `lookAhead` and `notFollowedBy` as your advice. But this time, error location is `1:1:`, but error message is `unexpected 'i'`. I expected it to be `unexpected 'if'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Finally. Solved the problem via `observing` function :D

Comment: Well, sorry for continuous self-commenting but.. turns out that `obeserving` method also had a problem. It failed to parse if there are trailing characters after reserved name, i.e. `ifa`, `thens`. I ended up with following method: if reserved name is parsed, then set source position to initial position of identifier using `setPosition`. This method fixes all the problems I had, but I'm still looking for a more elegant/haskell-ish solution.